# Maximizing Voltage with wind power

Tags: voltage

I created 2 simple blade configurations for a classroom wind turbine project. For our final evaluation of the project, we have to get our wind turbines to create the greatest voltage, at either high or low speed. Based on my own high-low speeds, I found that one, with only 2 thin blades, spun slower on the low speed and faster on the high speed. The other one, with 5 thin blades, spun pretty much exactly the same speed for high and low power (Faster than the low speed for the first blade, but slower than the high speed). Which one would produce the most voltage if they were wired the same? I heard that a faster spinning turbine might not generate as much voltage.

Comment: Please provide additional information like motor type.

Comment: Are the generators/turbines getting judged based on _open circuit_ voltage or _loaded_ voltage? _Open circuit_ voltage will be higher with higher RPM (assuming same generator parameters), but _loaded_ (i.e. across a resistance) voltage will only rise as a function of total power. - Even loaded, higher speed usually means higher voltage, but the speed of the turbine will be decreased by the back-torque of the generator under load, but you'd need to test with the same load resistance to verify which turbine will function more efficiently for that specific load.

Answer (score 1):

A wind turbine is not like a constant voltage source, the more current you draw from it the slower it turns. Eventually if you draw too much current, the blades will stall. The question is not how much voltage will it produce, depending on the motor, it may produce the same voltage. The question is, which turbine will produce the most power. For this you have to measure both voltage and current.

$$Power = Voltage*Current$$

The load will make the difference, and the power is dependent on how much torque the blades generate. If your doing an experiment, put a loading resistor on the generator, then put it on the other one. Measure the voltage and the current.

Comment: So basically, the one with greater torque should have more voltage?

Comment: That's basically it. If you have taken physics, energy is a great way to answer questions about systems. And the equations are usually straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

If, as you stated, voltage is the *only* measurement criterion for this test, then the blade system that can spin the motor fastest will 99% of the time generate the highest open-circuit voltage.

Most modern gererators/alternators/dynamos use inductive coils for 'poles' to generate usable electricity. The higher the frequency of excitation (i.e. the more times per second a 'pole' passes through a magnetic field), the higher the inductive reactance, thus the higher the potential voltage generated by the coil.

Of course, open-circuit voltage is a singular case & as soon as you load the circuit, dynamic forces come into play & the generator + blades will alter speed, voltage & current until they reach an equilibrium state where P(in)=P(out).

Also, your 5-bladed design likely works better in low-speed scenarios due to its higher 'wetted surface' to collect more torque from. As the speed increases, however, lower blade-count setups become more efficient due to losses generated by [tip vortices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wingtip_vortices). If you wanted to "go for the gold," it might be worth trying a monoblade, or ducted turbine design. These offer the 2 best ways to reduce tip vortex losses (to date).